# Xamarin.Forms, iOS only, Content of a frame that is the View of a ViewCell appear on top of other rows in the list

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, frame

I updated to the latest Xamarin.Forms version (4.7.0.1080) and now a list view I have in my project is totally messed up - the template of the list view is set to a custom view cell that it's View is set to a frame and now the content of the rows appear on top of each other.

I found this same problem in this sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/boxview-listviewcolors ([see screenshot here](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/m3/wvfln1609a3p.png))

Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` to the listview.Like:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >

  ...

</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks @leo-zhu-msft, my code is written in C# and when I add the CachingStrategy I get an error: Property or indexer 'ListView.CachingStrategy' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @ChasyAdler You mean you create the listview in behind code?If is ,you could write like var listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft Thanks!
I'm trying it now, I'll let you know if it fixed the problem.

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft The problem still occurs :(

Comment: @ChasyAdlerc As usual, the two expressions are equivalent，and the XAML approach worked for me.

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft You are right, it did fix, but in my project it fixed only partially -
I have a frame with a label in it that is added to the view cell OnBindingContextChanged and as soon as I start to scroll, the frames start to overlap with each other....

Comment: @ChasyAdler You could show some codes,it will be helpful.

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft In Xamarin's sample add BindingContextChanged to the ViewCell and in this methode try to add a Frame with a Label in it to the ViewCell frame's outer StackLayout - 
`var viewCell = sender as ViewCell;
            if (viewCell == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var contentView = viewCell.View as ContentView;
            var frame = contentView.Content as Frame;
            var stack = frame.Content as StackLayout;
            stack.Children.Add(new Frame { Content = new Label { Text = "111" } });`

Comment: You mean you generate frames dynamically?

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft Yes, I'm fetching data from a server based on data of the BindingContext and display it in a frame that I add to the existing view

Comment: @ChasyAdler Did it work before the update to the latest version?

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft It definitely worked - untill version 4.6.0.847

Comment: @ChasyAdler You could report it to the [XF github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)

Comment: @leo-zhu-msft [It's reported](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11266)